# How to work a button function more time?

Tags: android, opencv

I want to screen capture with OpenCV.For example one time touch screen but 5 take photos at the same time.Here's my code but I can capture only one time ;

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
        Random rnd=new Random();
        int number=rnd.nextInt(1000);
    Log.i(TAG,"onTouch event");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/opencv"+
                           "/"+number+"sample_picture_" + currentDateandTime + ".jpg";
    mOpenCvCameraView.takePicture(fileName);
    Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

     return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked whether those `fileNames` are the same or not?

Comment: Not same they have different file name everytime.I added random function and generate randim number on file name part

Answer (score 0):

you can enable a flag in onTouch function and take the pictures in onCameraFrame function. something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    takeFivePhotos = true;
    return true;
}
```

then in onCameraFrame function:

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Mat mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    if(takeFivePhotos == true){
        // have a counter for the number of photos written and write your photo in files.
    }       
    return mRgba;
}
```

and you can find the full class implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213230/opencv-with-android-camera-surfaceview/22504602#22504602) about how to get frame data.